# MySQL insert random values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Hi I want to inserting some random values from one table to another my query looks like that:

```
INSERT INTO `rounds`(`matchID`, `questionOneID`, `questionTwoID`, `questionThreeID`) VALUES (17,(SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3))
```

The problem is, that mysql wants 4 parameter (matchID, questionOneID,...) and only gets two (17,(...)) how do I tell MySql that it gets 3 parameters from the SELECT?
Did i really have to:

```
INSERT INTO `rounds`(`matchID`, `questionOneID`, `questionTwoID`, `questionThreeID`) VALUES (17,(SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),(SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),(SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1))
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Your query looks correct.  I would write it with `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO `rounds`(`matchID`, `questionOneID`, `questionTwoID`, `questionThreeID`)
     SELECT 17,
            (SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT `id` FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

If you want to guarantee that the three questions are different, then I might go for this approach instead:

```
INSERT INTO `rounds`(`matchID`, `questionOneID`, `questionTwoID`, `questionThreeID`)
    SELECT 17,
           substring_index(group_concat(id order by rnd), ',', 1),
           substring(substring_index(group_concat(id order by rnd), ',', 2), ',', 11),
           substring_index(group_concat(id order by rnd), ',', -1),
    FROM (SELECT id, rand() as rnd FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) q
```

This will put three random questions on one row, with no duplicates (unless `id` is duplicated in `questions`.